# Can't use function return value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I just don't get it where is the problem but here's the error:

> Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in
>   D:\wamp\www\system\classes\database.class.php on line 70

Code:

```
public function query($sql) {
        if(!is_string() or empty(trim($sql))) {
            throw new Exception('No sql statement was entered.');
        }

        $query = @mysql_query($sql);

        if(!$query) {
            throw new Exception('Query could not be executed because of an error: [#' . mysql_errno() . '] - ' . mysql_error());
        }

        return $query;
    }
```

Line 70:

```
 if(!is_string() or empty(trim($sql))) {
```

Comment: Did you look up the functions you're using, at all? Even just the ones on line 70? Any research performed at all during the debugging of this problem?

Comment: I got my answer no need to be smartass now.

Comment: Your response confirms to me that you only care about your immediate issue, your immediate answer, with little regard for the community providing the free help, or any continuing involvement with it once you've snatched what you need! Please respect us in future questions by performing your own research first -- it'll make you a _much_ better developer, which is really why I brought it up. I was snarky about it because I find it a little insulting when someone has _not even bothered to open up the function's manual page_, with the answer clearly spelled out on that page. G'luck.

Comment: Sure, like I help others immediately when they need help (if i know the answer). There is no point in your first comment after I actually got the answer I wanted. Sure it might be my mistake of not using 'Google' at first place but I didn't ask for your opinion about anything.

Comment: (The "point" is to educate you for the future.) One of the great things about Stack Overflow is that, whilst you get quality knowledge and expertise for free, I get to give you my opinion whether you like it or not. Please, perform research in future: it's offensive to be so lazy then ask somebody else to do all the work for you! Cheers & hth.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's right there in the manual for the empty function: http://php.net/empty

> empty() only checks variables as anything else will result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not work: empty(trim($name)).

To fix it you need to do something like:

```
$sql = trim($sql);
if(!is_string() or empty($sql)) {
...
}
```

Comment: +1 for possibly the most obvious answer with the best reference of all time.

Comment: @Dzoki Yes, just store the processed value in a variable and then check with empty. I've added some example code.

Comment: @Dzoki: Simply do `!trim($sql)`. Although the proper way would be `trim($sql) === ''`. Also, you're missing an argument for `is_string()`.

Comment: @draevor: I don't think storing it in an variable is actually useful here. `$sql` will always be defined (it's passed as an argument). Just checking the result of `trim` for an empty value (like in my previous comment) will do. There's no point using `empty` if you are sure the variable is defined.

Comment: @netcoder Of course, if he only needs to do the check once or doesn't need the string trimmed further down the road, your comment is perfectly valid. I've written it like this just as a solution to the empty issue.